# Getting started with Vagrant, [ vagrant up, Connection Refused ]

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to get started with Vagrant following the documentation at:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html

I installed vagrant for my OS and have VirtualBox installed. I ran the following commands

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32

$ vagrant up
```

I get the following error message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32"]
Error: Failed connect to atlas.hashicorp.com:9999; Connection refused
```

I googled a bit trying to find why Connection was refused, didnt get any answer. I guess the problem is with the Vagrant server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had been googling about the problem with no luck. I tried tunneling my network connection to an AWS ec2 instance hosted in Germany and it worked. No more connection refused. I guess it was a problem with my specific connection. I cannot figure out why.